# How to use more generic IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the code as follows:

```
PropertyInfo p_info_keys = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Keys");
IEnumerable<string> keys = (IEnumerable<string>)p_info_keys.GetValue(obj, null);

foreach (string key in keys)
{
    // Some code
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = (IEnumerable<string>)p_info_keys.GetValue(obj, null);
```

Because it can be:

```
IEnumerable<decimal> keys = (IEnumerable<decimal>)p_info_keys.GetValue(obj, null);
```

I've tried to use this:

```
IEnumerable<object> keys = (IEnumerable<object>)p_info_keys.GetValue(obj, null);
```

But, of course, it doesn't work.

So, how can I use more generic construction that can accept both string and decimal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Someone tagged this as `Java` but it looks more like `C#`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use the fact that `IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable keys = (IEnumerable) p_info_keys.GetValue(obj, null);

foreach (object key in keys)
{
    ...
}
```

Of course, you don't then have the type of the key at compile-time, but if you're trying to use the same non-generic code for both cases, then that wouldn't be possible anyway.

Another alternative is to do this in a generic method:

```
public void Foo<T>(...)
{
    IEnumerable<T> keys = (IEnumerable<T>) p_info_keys.GetValue(obj, null);

    foreach (T key in keys)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @elyashiv: Yes, but that won't make any difference. The compiler would just infer the type as `IEnumerable` in the first case or `IEnumerable<T>` in the second case. It would reduce the number of characters in the code, but that's the *only* effect.